# @ng-bootstrap, *ngFor and dynamic columns

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

I have an array of items which I want to display in a grid, and have 3 items per row. I'm using `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` in my Angular 7 application. Using an `*ngFor` I can't figure out how to have it actually do that.  I've got a small [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1asfjx) which just does this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <label class="col-4" *ngFor="let name of items">
      <input type="checkbox" >{{ name }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had assumed that since each label said `col-4` that it would end up forcing a new row after every third item.

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Comment: It doesn't make a grid that's only 3 columns wide.  It's putting everything on one row still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-berccv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

you forgot to add class row and bootstrap to stackblitz

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <label class="col-4" *ngFor="let name of items">
      <input type="checkbox" >{{ name }}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
 ng-bootstrap is just the javascript for dropdown etc, but you need to install the bootstrap.css file too  check New [blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvvaxs?file=src/app/app.component.html) in angular.json

```
    ],
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "src/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```

on your machine you will do ( if using npm)

```
npm i bootstrap --save
```

then in angular.json

```
            "styles": [
...
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
...
            ],
```

Comment: I tried to expand this now to my more real usage (inside of a form) and I'm hitting the same problem still.  I added the `row` class.  Not sure where you mean I forgot to add bootstrap as I see the dependency listed.  Here's my updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1asfjx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.  I'm just not seeing in your working example where you actually added that as it's not in the angular.json styles nor the index as a link.  In my actual project I verified that the bootstrap.min.css is definitely being loaded.